# Magnetron symbol with circuitikz

Tags: symbols, circuitikz

The package `circuitikz` does not have vacuum tube symbols, so I have to create it. I do not know how it's done, I need your help.

[image: magnetron]

Comment: As for how it's done, I have some tutorials on my web site (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm).  It's not exactly a bipole, what with a heater/cathode, nor does it follow the standard tripole layout (all leads in line with the origin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are, if it is ok, i will include it to the next circuitikz relase:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\ctikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/magnetron/width/.initial=1}
\pgfdeclareshape{magnetron}
{
    \savedanchor\northwest{
            \pgf@y= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
            \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/magnetron/width}\pgf@y
            \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
            \pgf@x= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
            \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/magnetron/width}\pgf@x
            \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{anode}{
    \northwest
    \pgf@circ@res@step= \pgf@y
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{-90}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    }
    \anchor{cathode1}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@step= \pgf@y
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{105}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    }
    \anchor{cathode2}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@step= \pgf@y
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{75}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    }
      \anchor{text}{
        \pgfpointorigin
        \advance \pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance \pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{left}{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{right}{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{top}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{pathstart}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{pathend}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{bottom}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{east}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{west}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{south}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{north}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
        \backgroundpath{
        \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}
        \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{tripoles/magnetron/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
            \northwest
            \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y 
            \pgf@circ@res@down = -\pgf@y
            \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x  
            \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@res@other}{sin(15)*\pgf@circ@res@up}

        \pgfscope
            \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

            %create outer circle
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}} {\pgf@circ@res@right}
            \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
            \pgfusepath{draw}
            %create chambers
             \foreach \angle in {45,135,225,315}{
                        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{\angle}{0.4\pgf@circ@res@right}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{ \pgfpointpolar{\angle}{\pgf@circ@res@right}}
                    }
            \pgfsetroundcap
            \pgfusepath{draw}
            \pgfscope
            %draw connection from outside
            %anode
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0\pgf@circ@res@right}{.15\pgf@circ@res@down}}
                %cathodes
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{105}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{75}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfsetbuttcap
                \pgfusepath{draw}
            \endpgfscope
            %create cathode
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{.15\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                        \pgfusepath{draw}
            %create anode
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@circ@res@left}{.15\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@circ@res@right}{.15\pgf@circ@res@down}}

            \pgfsetbuttcap
            \pgfusepath{draw}
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[L]++(0,-2);
    \draw (2,-1) node[magnetron,scale=1](magn){};
    \draw (magn.anode) --++(0,-1)node[rground]{};
    \draw (magn.cathode1)--++(0,1)node[above]{$1$}; 
    \draw (magn.cathode2)--++(0,1)node[above]{$2$};
    \draw[->](magn.east) --++(1,0)node[right]{$RF_{out}$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Best regards,

Stefan

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very very very very much.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the Stefan code and I think it is better:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\ctikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/magnetron/width/.initial=1}
\pgfdeclareshape{magnetron}
{
    \savedanchor\northwest{
            \pgf@y= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
            \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/magnetron/width}\pgf@y
            \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
            \pgf@x= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
            \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/magnetron/width}\pgf@x
            \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{anode}{
    \northwest
    \pgf@circ@res@step= \pgf@y
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{-90}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    }
    \anchor{cathode1}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@step= \pgf@y
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{105}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    }
    \anchor{cathode2}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@circ@res@step= \pgf@y
        \pgfpointorigin
        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{75}{\pgf@circ@res@step}}
    }
      \anchor{text}{
        \pgfpointorigin
        \advance \pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance \pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    \anchor{left}{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{right}{%
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{top}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{pathstart}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{pathend}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{bottom}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
    \anchor{east}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{west}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{south}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{north}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@x=0pt
    }
       \backgroundpath{
        \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}
        \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{tripoles/magnetron/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
            \northwest
            \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y 
            \pgf@circ@res@down = -\pgf@y
            \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x  
            \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@res@other}{sin(15)*\pgf@circ@res@up}

        \pgfscope
            \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

            %create outer circle
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}} {\pgf@circ@res@right}
            \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
            \pgfusepath{draw}
            %create chambers
             \foreach \angle in {45,135,225,315}{
                        \pgfpathmoveto{ \pgfpointpolar{\angle}{0.6\pgf@circ@res@right}}
                        \pgfpathlineto{ \pgfpointpolar{\angle}{\pgf@circ@res@right}}
                    }
            \pgfsetroundcap
            \pgfusepath{draw}
            \pgfscope
            %draw connection from outside
            %anode
                \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0\pgf@circ@res@right}{.5\pgf@circ@res@down}}
                %cathodes
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{105}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{75}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                \pgfsetbuttcap
                \pgfusepath{draw}
            \endpgfscope
            %create cathode
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{.15\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
                        \pgfusepath{draw}
            %create anode
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@circ@res@left}{.5\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\pgf@circ@res@right}{.5\pgf@circ@res@down}}

            \pgfsetbuttcap
            \pgfusepath{draw}
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[L]++(0,-2);
    \draw (2,-1) node[magnetron,scale=1](magn){};
    \draw (magn.anode) --++(0,-1)node[rground]{};
    \draw (magn.cathode1)--++(0,1)node[above]{$1$}; 
    \draw (magn.cathode2)--++(0,1)node[above]{$2$};
    \draw[->](magn.east) --++(1,0)node[right]{$RF_{out}$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]